# what is the best practice to simulate test payments using actual API call in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, payment, simulate, payeezy

I am doing a Payment Transaction using `Payeezy`, here is my Payment Request Body.

```
{
"operation": "Sale",
"tender": "CC",
"accountNumber": "XXXXXXXXXXXX1881",
"accountType": "VISA",
"amount": "79",
"merchantId": "HOM_EZ",
"policyNumber": "19029W0042",
"payerName": "TEST-200",
}
```

I was thinking to check for the "payerName": "TEST-205" field and check if it starts with TEST, Any number following that will be used to simulate the amount used to test the payment errors shown here.

[Bank Response codes](https://support.payeezy.com/hc/en-us/articles/203730509-First-Data-Payeezy-Gateway-Bank-Response-Codes)

and

[Transaction codes](https://support.payeezy.com/hc/en-us/articles/203730499-eCommerce-Response-Codes-ETG-Payeezy-Gateway-Transaction-Codes-)
For eg if its `TEST-205`, I will change the simulation amount to **5207** to get the simulated error as shown in the above link.

I am using a spring boot application, all the apiKey, secretKey is declared in my `application.properties` which also has to be changed during the simulation.

What is the best practice to do this kind of simulation ?

Answer (score 2):

Payeezy offers demo accounts to test their payment API, [Payeezy Gateway Demo Accounts](https://support.payeezy.com/hc/en-us/articles/203730579-Payeezy-Gateway-Demo-Accounts).

You can then set up integretions tests to carry out API calls automatically.
Certain aspects could even be tested via unit testing, such as the validity of the credit card number.